# How to TextView height actually measure?

Tags: android, textview

I want to understand how actually `textView` final height calculates.

I tried following method for Measure Height of TextView.

```
public static int getHeight(Context context, String text, int textSize, int deviceWidth) {
        EmojiTextView textView = new EmojiTextView(context);
        textView.setText(text);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textSize);
        int widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(deviceWidth, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        int heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        textView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        float lineSpacingMulti = textView.getLineSpacingMultiplier();
        float lineSpacingExtra = textView.getLineSpacingExtra();
        float lineHeight = textView.getLineHeight();
        Log.d(TAG, "getHeight: lineSpacingMulti" + lineSpacingMulti + ":lineSpacingExtra:" + lineSpacingExtra + ":lineHeight:" + lineHeight);
        return textView.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
```

I got following logcat result :

```
09-17 12:11:18.974 25729-25729/?: getHeight: lineSpacingMulti1.0:lineSpacingExtra:0.0:lineHeight:43.0

09-17 12:11:18.973 25729-25729/?: calculateDynamicTextSize: ME Height 58
```

so if **line Height is 43** and **line spacing Multiplier is 1** than why **Height of Measure Text is 58**?

Comment: if you really want to know see `TextView#onMeasure` method, but what do you need it for actually?

Comment: @pskink I am measuring top and bottom padding for my text. so that if I put two textView in LinearLayout or one textView and one ImageView, space between them should look same.

Comment: see `TextView#setIncludeFontPadding`, but why not to use one `TextView` instead of merging two or more in `LinearLayout`?

Comment: @pskink setIncludeFontPadding has no value or I can say it has worse effect for some fonts. I have to support all system fonts. Two TextView is just an example. It can be any number.

Comment: use [this](http://pastebin.com/mTCAS0Ds) layout and notice the right text: it looks like one `TextView` but in fact they are three `TextViews` in one `LinearLayout`

Comment: @pskink Now if i change middle TextView with Image, will space between TextView - ImageView and ImageView - TextView same ?

Comment: change it and see it by yourself

Comment: and why do you want to merge two or more `TextView`s? why not just to use one `TextView`?

Comment: @pskink I checked it. I don't want to merge TextView. I want to tell what I want to achieve. Let me explain again.
If I put Two TextView in LinearLayout (Vertical) and One TextView and One ImageView in Another LinearLayout (Horizontal), I want to make space between them(i.e. TextView - TextView & TextView - ImageView) to same.

Comment: why do you want TWO or more TextViews in one LinearLayout?  why not just ONE TextView?

Comment: It is my requirement. :) It can be 2 or 2000 as per user data.

Comment: 2000 `TextView`s  inside a `LinearLayout`??? so your requirement is totally wrong then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123591/discussion-between-kaushlendra-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0):

When View is render the window calculates its position and height it will remain 58 even if you add one more line .Line height corresponds to painted text's height while textviews height corresponds to renderd view's height.  Play with it :try applying height of textview in dp like 30, then in wrap content and match parent  and see logcat. Let me know if it works

Comment: I got following result for TextSize 32.

    09-17 13:12:12.611 25729-25729/?: getHeight() called with: text = [Me], textSize = [32], deviceWidth = [1562]
    09-17 13:12:12.613 25729-25729/?: getHeight: lineSpacingMulti1.0:lineSpacingExtra:0.0:lineHeight:99.0:Line Bounds : Rect(0, 0 - 118, 132)
09-17 13:12:12.614 25729-25729/?: calculateDynamicTextSize: ME Height 132